Too many state variables in a reducer, but I want my component to render only when one of them changes
I created a reducer with many state variables,
And I am using it in my component like-
let gridData = useSelector((state: State) => state?.auditReducer).gridData;
will my component only update when gridDatachanges or when any state variable in auditReducer changes?

Whether it renders or not depends on what the selector function returns. If that value changes, the component renders. The selector function is (state: State) => state?.auditReducer, so any change to audit reducer will cause a rerender.
If you only want to render when gridData changes, then include that in the selector.
let gridData = useSelector((state: State) => state?.auditReducer.gridData);

